# Forgot password not working

Tags: password, troubleshooting

I have been trying to reset my admin password for my local install of wordpress running on MAMP. Previously had been working fine but I forgot the password but when I go through the process of 'Lost your password' I am meant to get an email with new password but it never arrives in my hotmail (also checked the junk) I know these can sometimes take a while  to come through but it has been a day now.. Any ideas I could try?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you dont have any mail server installed/enabled (like sendmail/qmail/postfix) in your local machine. You can still reset your admin password from database. The table "wp_users" stores the password in the "user_pass" field

You can just replace the value with a md5 hash value of your desired password for the admin user.

*Note: This is good for test/local environments and dont do so in Production server because it invalidates the effect of salt :)*

Comment: :-/ strange I tried changing it to MD5 function and changing the password in phpmyadmin a couple of times and it is still saying my password is wrong :-/

Comment: Sorry my bad, was using wrong database lol. Useful info especially about the effect on salt thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can reset the password via code also.
Below are the steps:

Paste the below code in your active theme's functions.php file.

```
wp_set_password('password',1);
```

Put in your own new password for the main admin user. The "1" is the user ID number in the wp_users table.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Resetting_Your_Password