# Locked out of WordPress admin area

Tags: login, password

I cant login into my website even when I input my correct login credentials. I tried to reset my password, but I did not receive the email. What can I do? Please help.
I have the access to cPanel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have access to cPanel, you can reset your password via phpMyAdmin.
Here is a tutorial. [How to Reset a WordPress Password from phpMyAdmin](http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/how-to-reset-a-wordpress-pass)

PS: There are many questions about this issue in Wordpress StackExchange, so please take a look at them.

Comment: If you're attempting to input an MD5 into the DB and it's not working, make sure it's lowercase. I had an MD5 generator give me uppercase letters and it didn't work. Lowercase works.

Answer (score 0):

The password reset is not working because your WP php mailer is not working due to incorrect setup. Similarly if thats the case, your registration and other emails won't work too. Check out the following article to fix that -http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-wordpress-not-sending-email-issue/

To recover access to your account, you will need to get into phpMyAdmin or use SQL commands. Checkout this well-written article from the official Wordpress Codex, https://codex.wordpress.org/Resetting_Your_Password

And there are so many similar questions already answered here at the StackExchange. Take a look at them too.

- [https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8321/locked-out-of-my-own-blog-and-password-reset-not-working](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8321/locked-out-of-my-own-blog-and-password-reset-not-working?rq=1)
- [https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/92059/forgot-password-not-working](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/92059/forgot-password-not-working?rq=1)